# downloading multiple files from URLs using powershell

Tags: powershell, scripting

I have a text file which consists of 100s of URLs. Those URLs again contain different installer files(.exe, .msi, .bat, .txt etc..)

I need to download those files onto my local machine using Invoke-WebRequest. But how can I download files without specifying the extension type of it in the Output path?

File.txt:

```
https://foo.com/path/to/file.exe?token=ahcdj009a
https://foo.com/path/to/file.msi?token=ansjndhkg
https://foo.com/path/to/file.lpr?token=553dndgbs
https://foo.com/path/to/file.txt?token=amnewa453
...etc
```

How do I download all the files from the URLs onto a Windows local machine using Invoke-WebRequest PowerShell command?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PowerShell Invoke-WebRequest, how to automatically use original file name?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25125818/powershell-invoke-webrequest-how-to-automatically-use-original-file-name) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23398479/download-multiple-files-from-http-using-powershell-with-proper-names and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38599653/download-files-from-the-internet-using-powershell-and-retain-file-name

Answer (score 0):

If the pattern stays this way (. + file extension + ?), you can use these two lines, while $fileExt is the file extension. Hope it helps a bit :)

```
$d -match "\.(\w+)\?"
$fileExt = $matches[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You wont want to use just iwr. You will need to use something in addition to that to download the files. Start-BitsTranfer should work.

If you want to download all linked images for example, you can try this:

```
$URL = "http://www.website.com"

$Site = iwr -Uri $URL

$Images = ($Site).Images.src

foreach ($Image in $Images) {

Start-BitsTransfer -Source $Image -Destination C:\Test\ -TransferType Download

}
```